# Moment.js stuck on 'a few seconds ago'

Tags: node.js, express, momentjs

I have recently deployed an application to Heroku; however, Moment.js always seems to be returning *a few seconds ago* when a comment or a post is submitted.

This is the relevant code in the app.js file:

```
var moment = require('moment');
app.locals.moment = require('moment');
```

These are the relevant schemas:

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            createdAt: {type:Date, default: Date.now},
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },  
    comments:[
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"
        }
    ]
});



var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author: {
        id:{
            createdAt: {type:Date, default:Date.now},
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
});
```

And this is the relevant EJS code:

```
<%= moment(comment.createdAt).fromNow() %>
```

Since in my schema I have defined that createdAt is now's date, should the time be output right?
Any help would be really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Just a quick note: Mongoose saves all dates in UTC

Comment: I think we need more details. You write: "Moment.js always seems to be returning 'a few seconds ago' when a [new] comment or a post is submitted." Isn't that correct? When someone creates a new comment, didn't it just get created a few seconds ago? Describe what you expect to see under diifferent circumstances, and then what you actually see.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear enough. Yes, it would have been created a few seconds ago, however it stays that way no matter how much time passes.

Comment: It stays that way until you update your view...